# Indexing previous records with Doctrine (and Symfony!) with Zend Lucene

Tags: zend-framework, symfony1, lucene, doctrine

I have a Symfony application that uses Doctrine as its ORM. Based on Symfony's "Practical symfony" book, I have Zend Lucene added to my web app.

However, the problem is that there are around 1.1 million rows existing in the database that I want to index for Lucene as well. The only things being indexed are edited rows and the rows have been added since I starting using Lucene (about 50-75k).

I'm not sure the best method to go about this, so I figured I would ask some opinions.

Comment: I recommend not using Zend Lucene especially for this amount of data. Solr might be a better fit (it's a lucene based as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a task that clears the current index and rebuilds it with all the records. It's on github, you can find it [here](http://github.com/maerlyn/tibiahu/blob/master/lib/task/TibiahuRebuildIndexTask.class.php). Although it uses propel, you should be able to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Used a Symfony task costumed to my own liking, thanks for the idea!